# Java run time error

Tags: java

I get following error when I try to run a Java program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Abc : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Abc. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

However, the error appears to be due to trying to run something compiled with Java 7 (class file version 51) with an earlier version of the Java interpreter.

Ubuntu 12.04 comes by default with OpenJDK 6, but version 7 is available in the repositories.

In a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

(or search for it in the software centre)

If you want to do any java development rather than just run a program you'll need also `openjdk-7-jdk`